# Добавление и сразу же удаление элемента списка

Tags: python, алгоритм, список

Как реализовать такой алгоритм: из списка находим max, добавляем в другой список, сразу же удаляем, потом находим min, так же добавляем в другой список и сразу удаляем. Постоянно выкидывает ошибку выхода за пределы массива ( делал через pop)

Comment: покажите код с ошибкой

Comment: for i in range(len(a)):
    b.append(max(a))
    a.pop(max(a))
    b.append(min(a))
    a.pop(min(a))  Знаю, что косяк в том, что длина изменяется, но как это исправить - не совсем понимаю

Comment: А зачем цикл? что такое a b и new  ? и код пишите в вопрос

Comment: А как тогда без цикла? Пройтись по len(a)//2? Смысл такой: Добавил> удалил, добавил >удалил

Comment: максимум у листа один, минимум тоже, зачем их много раз куда-то добавлять и убирать. Ну и если несколько раз, то искать то зачем несколько раз

Comment: Максимум один, только его значение меняется при удалении старого

Comment: приведите пример входного списка и того, что вы хотите получить на выходе

Comment: а где вы тут максимум удаляете? Действительно, покажите исходные данные, код и желдаемый результат

Comment: a = [6,6,7,7,7];
res = [7,6,7,6,7]

Comment: Это по работе или домашнее задание? Просто разные решения напишу

Comment: Домашнее задание. Есть какое-то различие в алгоритмах?

Comment: Можно отсортировать список и брать сначала и с конца последовательно, пока индексы не перекроются. Но от вас не это хотят

Comment: А понимание того, что в pop аргументом должен стоять индекс листа, а не значение. Вам надо найти индекс масимального элемента и его удалить. И так же для минимального. Вот и попробуйте такое сделать, дальше подскажем

Comment: В каком плане "не это хотят"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`O(n log n)` по времени, `O(n)` в памяти алгоритм:

```
from math import ceil

a = [2, 3, 1, 5, 4]
a.sort(reverse=True)
middle = ceil(len(a) / 2)
a[::2], a[1::2] = a[:middle], a[middle:][::-1]
print(a)  # -> [5, 1, 4, 2, 3]
```

`O(n log n)` по времени, `O(1)` в памяти алгоритм:

```
from collections import deque

a = [2, 3, 1, 5, 4]
a.sort()
q = deque()
while a:
    q.append(a.pop())

while q:
    a.append(q.popleft())
    if q:
        a.append(q.pop())
print(a)  # -> [5, 1, 4, 2, 3]
```

`O(n**2)` по времени, `O(1)` в памяти алгоритм:

```
a = [2, 3, 1, 5, 4]
b = []
odd = False
while a:
    b.append(a.pop((min if odd else max)(range(len(a)), key=a.__getitem__)))
    odd = not odd
print(b)  # -> [5, 1, 4, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

функциональное решение:

```
In [200]: import math
In [201]: from itertools import zip_longest, chain

In [202]: l = sorted(a, reverse=True)

In [203]: b = [x
               for x in chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(l[:math.ceil(len(l)/2)],
                                                        l[::-1][:len(l)//2]))
               if x]

In [204]: b
Out[204]: [7, 6, 7, 6, 7]
```

если совсем "в лоб":

```
In [169]: a = [6,6,7,7,7];

In [170]: l = sorted(a, reverse=True)
     ...: b = []
     ...: while l:
     ...:     b.append(l.pop(0))
     ...:     if l:
     ...:         b.append(l.pop(len(l)-1))
     ...:

In [171]: b
Out[171]: [7, 6, 7, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Тока страшный for замените на while l:

Comment: @splash58, спасибо, так симпатичнее! :)

Comment: Спасибо большое!